# vscode: output of a command as part of a string in launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have my launch.json file that contains:

```json
        {
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "name": "Rt117xDemo Start",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "executable": "${workspaceFolder}/FW/image/Rt117xDemo.elf",
            "servertype": "jlink",
            "device": "MIMXRT1176xxxA_M7",
            "interface": "swd",
            "rtos": "FreeRTOS",
            "svdFile": "${workspaceFolder}/FW/bsp/device/MIMXRT1175_cm7.svd",
            "runToEntryPoint": "main",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "serverArgs": [
                "-gui"
            ],
            "preLaunchCommands": [
                "directory ${workspaceFolder}/FW"
            ],
            "postLaunchCommands": [
                "monitor reg pc 0x30002100"
            ]
        }
```

I would like the address of the last line ("*monitor reg pc **0x30002100***") to be either the output of a bash command, or perhaps a "variable" (like `${workspaceFolder}`) that I would like to populate with the output of a bash command.

how can I achieve this?

**EDIT 2023-23-06**

I explain what I would like to do in this example.

I should run the following command:

```bash
/path/to/arm-none-eabi-readelf -l FW/image/Rt117xDemo.elf | sed -n 's/Entry point \(0x[[:xdigit:]]\{8\})/\1/p'
```

this command prints the address I need. It is taken from the compiled file so this command should be run every time I launch debugging (and certainly after running the build task).

so I'd like to be able to edit the launch.json line like this:

```json
"postLaunchCommands": [
    "monitor reg pc ${command: /path/to/arm-none-eabi-readelf -l ${workspaceFolder}/FW/image/Rt117xDemo.elf | sed -n 's/Entry point \(0x[[:xdigit:]]\{8\})/\1/p'}"
]
```

Comment: [Tasks Shell Input](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=augustocdias.tasks-shell-input)

Comment: @rioV8 Tasks Shell Input seems to run the command before the build, and this is a problem since the command itself processes the file produced by the build itself. It also presents me with a dropdown for choice, which I do not want.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) and the command:

`extension.commandvariable.file.content`

Use an `${input}` variable:

```json
"postLaunchCommands": [
  "${input:fileContent}"
]
```

Comment: Please can you give an example where there is also bash command?

Comment: @mastupristi you don't give information on when to execute the bash command and how dynamic the information is you get back

Comment: I have edited the original post in hopes of clarifying some of the points you listed

Answer (score -1):

most likely the variables in the launch config are resolved before any execution is performed.

You must split the `F5` that builds and starts a debug session into:

1. remove the `"preLaunchTask": "build"` from the `launch.json`
2. create a build task that compiles the code and modifies the `launch.json`
   This task can be a compound task or a shell script that calls the compiler, after compilation executes the `arm-none-eabi-readelf | sed` command and with the result modify `launch.json` with `awk` (a simple search/replace of the address.
   Modifying `launch.json` might be put in a shell script.
3. with the modified `launch.json` you now start the debugging with `F5`

**`/path/to/modify-launch.sh`**

```bash
#!/bin/sh
ADDRESS=(/path/to/arm-none-eabi-readelf -l $1/FW/image/Rt117xDemo.elf | sed -n 's/Entry point \(0x[[:xdigit:]]\{8\})/\1/p')
awk -v address=$ADDRESS '{found=match($0, /^(\s*"monitor reg pc )([^"]+)(".*)/, arr);if (found!=0) printf "%s%s%s\n", arr[1], address, arr[3]; else print $0;}' $1/.vscode/launch.json >$1/.vscode/launch.json.new
mv $1/.vscode/launch.json.new $1/.vscode/launch.json
```

(my bash is a bit rusty, but you see the point)

Assign the result of the command `arm-none-eabi-readelf | sed` to a variable and use that variable.

The workspace path to use is a parameter of the `modify-launch.sh` script. Pass it to the script from the task.

If you put `run-monitor.sh` in your `PATH` and give it exe permission you don't have to specify the path.

Comment: `monitor` is a gdb command, is not a system command

Comment: @mastupristi I have modified the answer